# How configure Vagrant so doesnt block forwarded ports on host when on private network

Tags: vagrant

I want a vagrant VM to behave like a box not hosted on my host machine.

I want to be able to do

```
curl <vagrant private ip> #nginx on the vm
```

and have that work from the host machine

```
curl localhost #e.g. iis
```

and have that work from the host machine

but it seems it's not possible as when you do port forwarding it always occupies the host port too on the loopback/or IP and you cant restrict it to just the private IP of the VM, basically, you cant have the VM running and start iis.

If that is the case ok, that's that.

currently, my Vagrant file has

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 80
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.11
```

I know the forwarded_port has guest_ip and host_ip settings but I didn't find they did anything when I tried to set to the private network IP.

Any suggestion of easy workaround also welcome.

Comment: Just remove your forward_port line / you'll access the VM through the private IP and the 80 port from this IP and you host 80 port will be free

Comment: Thanks Frédéric, that worked. I mistakenly thought that internal ports couldnt be seen unless mapped using port forwarding.